# Random pictures in two pages

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores images of three categories: cars, bikes, buses. These images appear on two pages. On the first page, you should see an image of each category, defined so random. On the second page, you should see the remaining pictures. How can I do this using php?

Comment: How do you plan on keeping track of which images were shown on the first page, so that the "rest" are shown on the remaining pages?  To the server, each page request is a separate, isolated event.

Comment: Maybe using session. But I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to do this in MySQL, you can set the order to:

`ORDER BY MD5(ImageNo+UserRandomNumber)`

[SQL FIddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8f41/10/0)

You can generate a single random number per user, store this in the session then apply this to the ordering and as long as the number supplied stays the same, the order will remain the same too.

Comment: But pictures can not be repeated.

Comment: Do you mean you can't have two picture categories repeated, eg. no two pictures of cars? Or do you mean this might repeat individual images?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a session to store which images were shown on the first page, and then leave them out on the second page. Without knowing your exact table structure, something like this should work:

```
<?php

// page 1
session_start();

function get_random_image_id($category)
{
    // SELECT id FROM images WHERE category = $category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
}

function show_image($id)
{
    // SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = $id
    // echo <img ...>
}

$_SESSION['image_ids'] = array(
    get_random_image_id("cars"),
    get_random_image_id("bikes"),
    get_random_image_id("buses"),
);

foreach($_SESSION['image_ids'] as $image_id)
{
    show_image($id);
}

?>

<?php

// page 2
session_start();

function show_images($exclude_ids)
{
    $ids = implode(",", $exclude_ids);
    // SELECT * FROM images WHERE id NOT IN ($ids)
}

$exclude = array();
if(isset($_SESSION['image_ids'])) // has the user visited page 1?
{
    $exclude = $_SESSION['image_ids'];
}

show_images($exclude);

?>
```

Comment: I would refine this by making the array associative so you can see which picture of which category was displayed.